# Using an image file as a placemark in qgis

Tags: qgis, symbology, labeling

I am making a map of sports clubs in London. I have each club's crest as image files (tiff) and want to make the placemark symbol using these images.

I know it's possible to upload images in the SVG format. The problem is I can't find a way of converting the tiff files to svg that gives satisfying results (crests are quite intricate at times).

Is there a way of adding tiff files (or png for that matter) as placemark symbols? Alternatively does anyone know of a satisfactory way of changing raster images to svg? Might there be an alternative way of doing this (an additional plugin maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately converting from a raster image to svg is the first step. According to [online-converter.com](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg) :

> If you convert from raster images like PNG or JPG, an SVG converter
>   will convert your shapes and objects to black and white vector
>   graphics that are scalable without any loss in quality. They can be
>   later refined or colored with a free vector graphic program like
>   Inkscape. Photographs will most likely not have the desired effect
>   when converted from raster to SVG format.

Ofcouse there are numerous raster2svg algorithms with varing results, but I think the above will always be valid in some extend.

The reason you need SVG is because their scalability, which can vary accordingly the scale of your map.

Another solution (which is a bit hackish) is at the cartographic composer to add an image overlay and add one-by-one every crest.

I would be very interested if someone else could provide a better solution.

Comment: Inkscape does the job very nicely. Didn't need to use online-converter.com as you can import tiff file and save them as svg in Inkscape. They come out with a good level of detail.

Thank you!